# Tensorflow VGG16 Attribute Error: module tensorflow has no attribute get_default_graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

Hi guys I just start learning the machine learning and tried to run a RCNN code on `Jupyter Notebook`.
I am trying to run the below code. I have google the error and update the `tensorflow` version to 2.3.1 and `kersa` 2.1.6. But it still throw out this `TypeError`. I see there is another way to amend the python source code by removing the argument `axis`. But how can I change the vgg16 sourcecode on `Jupyter Notebook`? I tried to go into `/use/local/lib` on my macbook and cannot find out the python source file. Hope someone can help! Cheers

Code:

```
from keras.application.vgg16 import VGG16
vggmodel = VGG16(weight='imagenet', include_top=True)
vggmodel.summary()
```

Update:
I have found the source file and remove the axis argument. But now another error is threw.

```
Tensorflow Attribute Error: module tensorflow has no attribute get_default_graph


AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-5b351c8334f5> in <module>
----> 1 vggmodel = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)
      2 vggmodel.summary()

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/applications/vgg16.py in VGG16(include_top, weights, input_tensor, input_shape, pooling, classes)
    107 
    108     if input_tensor is None:
--> 109         img_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
    110     else:
    111         if not K.is_keras_tensor(input_tensor):

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py in Input(shape, batch_shape, name, dtype, sparse, tensor)
   1455                              name=name, dtype=dtype,
   1456                              sparse=sparse,
-> 1457                              input_tensor=tensor)
   1458     # Return tensor including _keras_shape and _keras_history.
   1459     # Note that in this case train_output and test_output are the same pointer.

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name +
     90                               '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py in __init__(self, input_shape, batch_size, batch_input_shape, dtype, input_tensor, sparse, name)
   1317         if not name:
   1318             prefix = 'input'
-> 1319             name = prefix + '_' + str(K.get_uid(prefix))
   1320         super(InputLayer, self).__init__(dtype=dtype, name=name)
   1321 

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in get_uid(prefix)
     66     """
     67     global _GRAPH_UID_DICTS
---> 68     graph = tf.get_default_graph()
     69     if graph not in _GRAPH_UID_DICTS:
     70         _GRAPH_UID_DICTS[graph] = defaultdict(int)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: I just updated and included the full traceback error. Cheers